# Solution for Short Description in checkout woocommerce wordpress not working for me

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have used the Solution provided by brasofilo i found here [Short Description in checkout woocommerce wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127954/short-description-in-checkout-woocommerce-wordpress).

But for some reason, a colon gets added after every Description of every Product.

I used firebug to try to find out where that may come from. It shows up at the end of the dt class="variation-Productdescription" of every Product shown on the checkoutpage. Here is the code I copied from firebug:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="cart_item">
<td class="product-name">
<a href="http://shopurl/product/Product1/">Product1</a>
<strong class="product-quantity">× 1</strong>
<dl class="variation">
<dt class="variation-Productdescription">
<div class="post-content">
:
</dt>
<dd class="variation-Productdescription></dd>
</dl>
</td>
<td class="product-total">
</tr>
<tr class="cart_item">
</tbody>
```

Edit:

I can't upload images here yet as I am new, so I uploaded a screenshot of the problem to https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzQHZ.jpg

The Product Short Description doesn't have the colon.

[A Screenshot of the Product Short Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLq1h.jpg)

Edit 2:

A solution that is working for me right now is:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'wc_checkout_description_so_27900033', 10, 2 ); 
function wc_checkout_description_so_27900033( $other_data, $cart_item )
{
 $post_data = get_post( $cart_item['product_id'] );
 echo $post_data->post_excerpt;
 return $other_data;
 }
```

But as helgatheviking has pointed out, this is not a good solution, even though it works.

I will work on a better solution without the `echo`.

Comment: Can you show us output by screen shot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think sometime around WooCommerce v2.2 the `$other_data` variable in the checkout class was changed to an array requring `name` and `value` pairs. As such, the code from the other thread is outdated. Using it WooCommerce can't find the `name` or the `value` so those parts are blank and you are left with only the colon in between where they should be. Try this update:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'wc_checkout_description_so_27900033', 10, 2 );

function wc_checkout_description_so_27900033( $other_data, $cart_item )
{
    $post_data = get_post( $cart_item['product_id'] );
    $other_data[] = array( 'name' =>  'description', 'value' => $post_data->post_excerpt );
    return $other_data;
}
```

Comment: That works better. Can u tell me how i have to change the code, so that only the description is shown, without the description: before?
http://i.imgur.com/0wim8Oa.jpg

Comment: I have found a solution, by using the echo command.

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'wc_checkout_description_so_27900033', 10, 2 );
function wc_checkout_description_so_27900033( $other_data, $cart_item )
{
$post_data = get_post( $cart_item['product_id'] );
echo $post_data->post_excerpt;
return $other_data;
}

Now it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/i8O0qBl.jpg

Comment: It is hard to read code in comments. Better if you edit your question. That said, you shouldn't add an `echo` to a filter... as the part you are echoing just appears as soon as the `echo` is called and *not* necessarily where the output is desired. It might have worked in this case, but it isn't a good habit. Always `return $something` with a filter. In this case to modify how the other data is displayed you need to override WooCommerce's `cart/cart-item-data.php` template in your theme.

Comment: hi. have you ever displayed the product description to all of the product list? coz, I tried this solution but the description is displayed to 1 product only.