# Display WooCommerce cart item short description for a specific product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, categories

In WooCommerce I'm trying to add the product short description for a specific category in the cart items.

I found [**this code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900033/solution-for-short-description-in-checkout-woocommerce-wordpress-not-working-for) that adds the product short description to ALL products in the cart, but I can't figure out how to narrow it down to only display on specific products:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data', 'wc_checkout_description_so_27900033', 10, 2);

function wc_checkout_description_so_27900033($other_data, $cart_item) {
    $post_data = get_post($cart_item['product_id']);
    echo $post_data - > post_excerpt;
    return $other_data;
}
```

How can I make this code display the short description only for a defined product category?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update for woocommerce versions 3 and above

I have changed and actualized a little bit your code. Then to target a product category you should use [**`has_term()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) conditional WordPress function.

You will have to define in the function your categories IDs, slugs or names.

So here is the code for defined product categories terms:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data', 'filter_woocommerce_get_item_data', 10, 2);
function filter_woocommerce_get_item_data( $item_data, $cart_item ) {

    // Define HERE your Category term IDs, Slugs or Names in the array
    $categories = array('clothing', 'music'); 

    // Product Category condition Below
    if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        if( ! ( $cart_item['variationt_id'] > 0 ) ) {
            $description = $cart_item['data']->get_short_description();
        } else {
            $description = $cart_item['data']->get_description();
            
            if ( ! empty( $description ) ) {
                $parent_product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id'] );
                $description    = $parent_product->get_short_description();
            }
        }

        if ( ! empty( $description ) ) {
            $item_data[] = array(
               'key'       => __( 'Product description', 'woocommerce' ),
               'value'     => $description,
               'display'   => $description,
            );
        }
    }
    return $item_data;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Code is tested and works.